# Configure route to display pages in a SplitApp SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, json, sapui5

I have been trying to add pages to my SplitApp from other views (view.js) with their own drivers, but doing so causes the following error:

```
Sap-ui-core.js: 174 Uncaught Error: failed to load 'view / GestionDePlanta.view.js' from openui5-1.40.8 / resources / view / GestionDePlanta.view.js: 404 - Not Found (...)
```

I think it has to do with the paths to access that view the moment it boots

```
Sap.ui.view ({id: "GestionDePlanta", viewName: "view.GestionDePlanta", type: sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.JS});
```

Anyone know any way to do it?

I was following a tutorial, which I found easy to understand, but apparently this is incomplete :
http://blog.mypro.de/2014/02/14/add-page-to-ui5-boilerplate/

Thank you so much.

**Index.html**

```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <title>DatosMaestros</title>

        <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
            src="/openui5-1.40.8/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
            data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m,sap.ui.commons,sap.ui.table"
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
            data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
        </script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/utilityFunction.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/xml2json.js"></script>

        <script>
                 sap.ui.localResources("P_GestionDePlanta");

        var url = "http://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Employees",
            oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(url, true);

        sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel);

        var app = new sap.m.SplitApp("appId",{mode:sap.m.SplitAppMode.ShowHideMode});
        var master = sap.ui.view({id:"GestionDePlanta", viewName:"view.GestionDePlanta", type:sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.JS});
        app.addMasterPage(master);
        var detail = sap.ui.view({id:"PlanAbastecimiento", viewName:"view.PlanAbastecimiento", type:sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.JS});
        app.addDetailPage(detail);
        app.placeAt("content");

        </script>
    </head>

    <body class="sapUiBody" id="content">
    </body>

</html>
```

**Component.js**

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/UIComponent",
    "sap/ui/Device",
    "P_GestionDePlanta/model/models"
], function(UIComponent, Device, models) {
    "use strict";

    return UIComponent.extend("P_GestionDePlanta.Component", {

        metadata: {
            manifest: "json"
        },

        /**
         * The component is initialized by UI5 automatically during the startup of the app and calls the init method once.
         * @public
         * @override
         */
        init: function() {
            // call the base component's init function
            UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);

            // set the device model
            this.setModel(models.createDeviceModel(), "device");
        }
    });
});
```

**Manifiest.json**

```
{
    "_version": "1.1.0",
    "sap.app": {
        "_version": "1.1.0",
        "id": "P_GestionDePlanta",
        "type": "application",
        "i18n": "i18n/i18n.properties",
        "applicationVersion": {
            "version": "1.0.0"
        },
        "title": "{{appTitle}}",
        "description": "{{appDescription}}",
        "sourceTemplate": {
            "id": "ui5template.basicSAPUI5ApplicationProject",
            "version": "1.32.0"
        }
    },

    "sap.ui": {
        "_version": "1.1.0",
        "technology": "UI5",
        "icons": {
            "icon": "",
            "favIcon": "",
            "phone": "",
            "phone@2": "",
            "tablet": "",
            "tablet@2": ""
        },
        "deviceTypes": {
            "desktop": true,
            "tablet": true,
            "phone": true
        },
        "supportedThemes": [
            "sap_hcb",
            "sap_bluecrystal"
        ]
    },

    "sap.ui5": {
        "_version": "1.1.0",
        "rootView": {
            "viewName": "P_GestionDePlanta.view.GestionDePlanta",
            "type": "JS"
        },
        "dependencies": {
            "minUI5Version": "1.30.0",
            "libs": {
                "sap.ui.core": {},
                "sap.m": {},
                "sap.ui.layout": {}
            }
        },
        "contentDensities": {
            "compact": true,
            "cozy": true
        },
        "models": {
            "i18n": {
                "type": "sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel",
                "settings": {
                    "bundleName": "P_ProcesamientoDeArchivos.i18n.i18n"
                }
            }
        },
        "resources": {
            "css": [{
                "uri": "css/style.css"
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

**Folders**

[Image:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTf2S.png)

Comment: Well, it doesn't make much sense to say you don't know how even though you followed a tutorial. Is there something in the tutorial you don't understand? Something you're blocked on? I don't see any question for me to answer here.

Comment: I have seen several ways to do it, but the tutorial I left, I found the simplest, but still I can not get the views to be added to my split. That is my "blockade"

Comment: OK, welcome to SO. You need to learn to ask a question right. I can't make head or tail of your question, or absence thereof. Edit it; make it as clear as you can, and detail what you have tried, and what exactly your blocker is.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, there edit my question. Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that tutorial you followed is quite outdated. You would want to use a Component based structure (You have a component in your sample but never use it). The official [SAPUI5](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/)/[OpenUI5](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/) Developer Guide especially the walkthroughs are mostly up to date. I recommend you to do the [walkthrough](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/3da5f4be63264db99f2e5b04c5e853db.html) there.

Back to your problem: UI5 has its own way to resolve modules (≈javascript files) from names.

In your example you give UI5 the name of a view: `"view.GestionDePlanta"`. *view* is the namespace and *GestionDePlanta* is the module name. So UI5 looks for the namespace *view* and – lacking any matching namespace-path-mappings – it defaults to the UI5 framework itself using the same path as the `sap-ui-core.js` you defined in the bootstrap `<script>` element: **./openui5-1.40.8/resources/view**.

To add such an namespace-path-mapping you can use the [sap.ui.localResources()](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.html#.localResources) function.

With your `sap.ui.localResources("P_GestionDePlanta");` declaration UI5 would look for a module `"P_GestionDePlanta.view.GestionDePlanta"` in the folder **./P_GestionDePlanta/view**.

Thats better already but your folder structure should look like this then:

```
+ P_GestionDePlanta
  + view
      GestionDePlanta.view.js
  + controller
      GestionDePlanta.controller.js
index.html
```

An other way would be to use [jQuery.sap.registerModulePath()](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/jQuery.sap.html#.registerModulePath) to add an namespace-path-mapping. With `jQuery.sap.registerModulePath("P_GestionDePlanta", "./");` UI5 would look for a module `"P_GestionDePlanta.view.GestionDePlanta"` in the folder **./view**.

With that you can keep your folder structure:

```
+ view
    GestionDePlanta.view.js
+ controller
    GestionDePlanta.controller.js
index.html
```

But either way you have to supply the full namespace starting with *P_GestionDePlanta* everywhere like so:

```
sap.ui.view({id:"GestionDePlanta", viewName:"P_GestionDePlanta.view.GestionDePlanta", type:sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.JS});
```